# In X-Men: First Class, is Alex Summers related to Scott Summers?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-first-class

If they are related, then what is his relation to Scott Summers and how does this explain the age gaps between Scott and Professor X?

Comment: Believable to who? Many people from all across the world have siblings 20 years older than them. Like me. One 15 and one is 20, years older that is.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He is Scott Summers' younger brother in the comics, adopted out at a young age after the plane crash killed their parents.  However in X-Men: First Class he was conceived as an independant character.

> When questioned of Havok & Cyclops' "brother" relation, “Yes, the time
>   line is different,” Singer said. “It wouldn’t physically fit for him
>   to be the brother of Cyclops. We take some liberties on that.”

Bryan Singer, producer of the movie, interviewed at http://www.comicbookmovie.com/fansites/MarvelFreshman/news/?a=29870

Obviously the age difference betwen him, Professor X and Cyclops doesn't matter in that case - Havok's age is independent of Cyclops'.

Comment: That's for the comics, but their ages in the movies don't match that at all.

Comment: Updated for the movie.

Comment: Awfully dumb of Singer to burn that bridge, too. He could have just switched it so that Scott was the younger brother, or they're around the same age and just have the same father. Something that would give future writers wriggle-room, y'know?

Comment: See phantom42's answer for the family details discovered in the sequel to First Class, X-Men: Apocalypse.

Answer (score 14):

The original [x-men-cinematic-universe](/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe) backstory for Alex apparently included a foster sister, as Lucas Till mentioned [in this interview with IGN](http://www.ign.com/articles/2011/04/27/x-men-first-class-havok-interview), but this was all cut from the final theatrical cut of the film.

While Bryan Singer previously said that [Scott and Alex were not brothers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/18175/5184), he apparently changed his mind on this fact.

During the production of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, he [posted this photo](https://www.instagram.com/p/2RT_d9xD-P/):

[image: singer lied to us]

> Parents of #ScottSummers #Cyclops and #AlexSummers #Havok watch the end of the world as they know it unfold on TV #XMEN #XMenApocalypse #3ALITYTechnica

In the final cut of *X-Men: Apocalypse*, multiple mentions of Scott and Alex being brothers are made, including Alex specifically introducing Scott as his brother.

While possible that they are not related by blood, the Summers share the same parents, making them brothers.

Comment: How can this not have an upvote?  +1

Comment: Possibly the inaccurate use of the “marvel-cinematic-universe” tag.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite thanks. was half asleep when editing.

Answer (score -1):

They are brothers in the original comics with Alex being the older brother, in X-Men:First Class, Alex was with Xavier before Xavier found Scott. At the end of X-Men: Origins: Wolverine when the Professor is waiting in a wheelchair after Logan frees the mutants from the island. Because Wolverine happened not so soon after First Class. So Alex met Xavier first, making him the older brother in the timeline between First Class and Wolverine.

Comment: First Class takes place in 1962 and Wolverine takes place in 1981.  19 years is a little more than a short time later.  Alex being roughly late teens, or early twentys would make him too old to realisticlly be Scott's brother.

Answer (score -2):

exclude the comic fact, considering the timeline, alex summers might be scott summer's uncle or father

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE! Why would we exclude the comic fact ? Can you cite any source within the movie canon that backup you statement ?

Comment: @Kalissar, why should we exclude "the comic fact"? Probably because they are two different continuities/universes.

Answer (score -3):

Sure it's possible first class took place before wolverine had his movie . On witch cyclops was a kid  at least 10 or 12

Comment: Hello and welcome to Scifi.SE! "Sure, it's possible" without any related source is not a really good answer. Maybe you can improve it by adding some material? Have fun browsing the site :)