# Was Xavier's surprise at Magneto's helmet ever retconned?

Tags: marvel, x-men

X-Men Origins: Wolverine and X-Men: First Class introduced a few major continuity issues. Some of these have been half-addressed. For example,

- [Alex Summers is no longer Scott's younger brother](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18174/in-x-men-first-class-is-alex-summers-related-to-scott-summers)

> When questioned of Havok & Cyclops' "brother" relation, “Yes, the time line is different,” Singer said. “**It wouldn’t physically fit for him to be the brother of Cyclops.** We take some liberties on that."

- [Emma Frost, the White Queen is NOT in X-Men Origins: Wolverine](http://www.iamrogue.com/news/interviews/item/4757-iar-exclusive-interview-producer-lauren-shuler-donner-talks-%E2%80%98x-men-first-class%E2%80%99-cameos-a-possible-sequel-emma-frost-%E2%80%98the-wolverine%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98deadpool%E2%80%99.html)

> *Is January Jones’ Emma Frost somehow the same character we saw in X-Men Origins: Wolverine?*
>
> Donner: **No, she’s Emma from First Class. That’s who she was and she’s the real Emma Frost.** I think January did a pretty good job of portraying her.
>
> *So there is no connection between the First Class Emma Frost and the one we see in X-Men Origins: Wolverine?*
>
> Donner: **No … not really, no.**

One of the ones that I can't find any retconned explanation for is Charles' seeming inability to explain how Magneto had found a way to block his telepathy during the first X-Men movie. (Sorry, the only script I can find online is an early draft, so I can't find an exact quote at the moment). During the final battle of First Class,

> Charles clearly sees Magneto wearing Shaw's helmet, knowing that it blocks his telepathy.

Has this ever been explained either through supplemental material or another interview, or is this one of the gaping holes?

Comment: Maybe in the intervening years, Charles has reason to believe/know that Shaw's helmet is destroyed or otherwise made inaccessible to Magneto, and his surprise is that Magneto either has it again or has found a way to recreate it? Or perhaps, as Eric and Charles were friends, it was more surprise that he would be wearing the helmet, an act which shows a lack of trust, and this offended/shocked Charles (not saying that would be reasonable on his part, but they did have a pretty messed-up friendship)

Comment: Emma Frost was one of the young mutants held by Striker at TMI. And was explained to be Logan's girlfriend's sister.

Comment: @IhorSypko, yes, but as the link I provided explains, that "Emma Frost" was retconned to no longer be the same "Emma Frost" as the one in X-Men: First Class.

Comment: AFAIR, the "Emma Frost" from Origins is never actually called Emma Frost, just Emma. People online just started calling her Emma Frost because she was a blond telepath named Emma.

Comment: Similar thing happened in X-Men: Days of Future Past. Bryan Singer made an offhand remark in an interview that Juggernaut was supposed to be the 'guy' Wolverine knew, but ultimately decided Quicksilver would be cooler. Only problem is, the "I knew a guy, he'd be a young man now." ends up being confusing because they forgot to change the dialogue

Answer (score 2):

It's a gaping hole. Like a large number of prequels, the events of both movies cannot possible mesh without a large number of hoop jumping. It isn't addressed in the movie support comics and they can't really go back and take out the line of dialogue in the first Xmen movie, because nobody has come up with a way to ret-con actual reality.

Some basic links for people who need to read more:

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men%3a_First_Class) - where you can see a ton of links to interviews from the various fansites with the many authors of the script, as well as the director and a few with the original director turned producer.

The [132,000 results that Google turns up when you search Xmen First class plot holes](https://www.google.com/search?q=first+class+plotholes&oq=first+class+plotholes&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j60l2.6098&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=3&gs_ri=psy-ab&gs_mss=xmfirst%20class%20plotholes&tok=M4IKHuF59wwd2xrDWgK82Q&pq=first%20class%20plotholes&cp=4&gs_id=1x&xhr=t&q=x+men+first+class+plot+holes&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&tbo=d&sclient=psy-ab&oq=xmenfirst+class+plotholes&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.aWc&fp=97112852630437fb&biw=1821&bih=940). Spoiler alert! This one gets mentioned a rather large amount.

But wait! There's more! They might be able to turn it around, since the First Class prequels are supposed to a trilogy. That means there is always the possibility that Professor X will make it all a dream in the third movie. We can only hope!

Comment: Could you please provide a list of which support comics could be possibly addressing this- but aren't? (which is what would turn this answer from "duh! plot hole!" snipe into an [excellent well researched one](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/962/976).)

Comment: @DVK the comics have the same name as the movie... their what the original (and many subsequent scripts) were based on. You know, because the script went through seven different writers. People who ask crappy plothole questions get crappy plothole answers.